# Monitor Domain Admins and Enterprise Admin Group

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I would like to monitor my AD Groups "Domain Admins", "Enterprise Admins", "Schema Admins" etc.

I would like to monitor if they have any member user besides Administrator and my custom user and if found generate an alert with all the usernames in that alert.

I want to specify users and groups in a variable.

So far I found only found this code.

```
$currentMembers = Get-AdGroupMember -Identity 'Domain Admins' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: Would you like a email when members changed?

Comment: I just want to produce a CSV.

Comment: Please read the help for [Export-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7) including the examples to learn how to use it.

Comment: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is not a *free* code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. [After doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).